# How much power can a 6 nm transistor handle?

Tags: transistors, cpu, power-consumption

Modern semiconductors are manufactured with feature sizes measured in nanometers. For example, the EPYC 9654 CPU has 78840 million transistors. Each one is in 6 nm and has a TDP of 360 W. What is confusing me is the power consumption.

**(The picture below is JUST to give an idea about the nanometer scale ONLY)**

[picture source](https://www.azonano.com/news.aspx?newsID=38347)

[image: scale]

The atoms are in the picometer scale. I mean a transistor of 6 nm must be made of just a dozen atoms. How much power can a 6 nm transistor handle at frequencies in GHz without burning out?

A simple mathematical calculation:
360÷78840(million)= 5 nW per transistor.

**Edit:**
As some members pointed out not all transistors will switch on in the same time this mean each transistor will dissipate more than 5nW and yes not all the power is dissipated only by those tiny transistors but is still a lot.
CPU's operate with ~1 volt that means:
I=P÷V
I=360!!
This 360 amps is going into a 397 mm^2. Even the AWG 40 can't handle that at its fusing current rating.

[image: specs]

Comment: 6nm also isn't a measurement, so the transistors are typically quite a lot larger.

Comment: the transistors do not activate one at a time

Comment: @jsotola so each transistor consume more than 5 nw

Comment: 6 nm is a "minimum feature size" which roughly corresponds to the smallest part of a transistor being around that size.  The actual device is larger as it is made up of several parts, most of which are going to be larger than 6 nm.

Comment: 6nm is not a minimum feature size or even a size at all. It's just a name with no physical significance beyond the marketing department. The actual fin dimensions for a 6/7nm class node are ~10 nanometers wide by ~50nm high, although these numbers vary (and the height actually gets larger as you go to smaller nanometer nodes!).

Comment: As for why a 6nm transistor can dissipate pico to maybe microwatts, silicon is really thermally conductive and chips have big heatsinks clamped onto them. Higher power transistors will also be made of more fins which gives them a lot more surface area to dissipate from.

Comment: @autodidact It's not about watts. Wrong question! Differing levels of watts that can be handled will relate to mounting details and methods of cooling, which is external to a transmission gate or inverter. It's really about temperature-related metalization failure mechanisms (there are perhaps a dozen of these categories.) (Only a few dopants (boron) are affected at similarly lower temps.)

Comment: @periblepsis my question is about power that is going to to that tiny transistor. Shouldn't be less?

Comment: Something is **deeply** wrong about the graphic you show. Like, what is "10 hydrogen atoms laid side by side"? That makes no sense at all, that's not how atom work, at all. The covalent radius, so the distance between two H atoms that form a molecule, would be 0.03 nm; aside from a 10-hydrogen molecule not possibly existing, nor making a straight line, that would be much shorter. So do they mean Van der Waals radius? Same thing, but for weaker bonds due to polarity of molecules "butting" into each other; but that would still be much less than 0.7 nm. So, Bohr radius? that'd be 0.05 nm, not 0.7

Comment: And however these are arranged, how is a 10-atom complex larger than the farking diameter of a strand of DNA? Like, a single Desoxyguanosintriphosphate (the letter "G" in these genome-describing strings) is only *half* of such a diameter, and has 16 hydrogen atoms, 10 (significantly larger) carbon, 13 oxygen, 5 nitrogen and 13 oxygen atoms, plus whatever. And that's supposed to be less half the size? Wherever you got that graphic from, time to question your sources, and quite significantly so! (The DNA diameter is "about right", the hydrogen thing is totally out of this world.)

Comment: Yah, I get the hydrogen covalent radius at 25pm (from this wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius).

Comment: @MarcusMüller its not me who designed the "graphic" hydrogen is the smallest one the objectif was just to give an example how tiny things in nano scale, we know that atoms is between 0.1 and 0.5 [https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom] IF we can arange them in a line  we gonna have 600 atoms of hydrogen hope i clarified things for you.

Comment: Nah, that still is not how atoms "work"; see the definition of "Bohr Radius" vs "Covalent Radius", to understand why trying to assign a diameter to an atom is… basically impossible, because it's not something with a fixed dimensionality regardless of context.  But hint: this graphic is what I call "useless filler": it is distracting, and doesn't contribute to your question. I personally would avoid including things like that in questions. You're looking for advise, not to have the most "click bait" looking blog entry :D

Comment: So, after thinking about this for a while now, I went ahead and removed the graphic: it really contributed nothing (but a wrong idea of how you can space atoms), and it was much larger than necessary, and it just distracted, and nothing had anything to do with semiconductor technology, so, it was really just not *good* for your question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for the advise :)

Comment: @autodidact another useless "scale of things" picture isn't any better. Don't add stuff to your question to make it look like it's from a children's book – add relevant research instead. (by the way your new graphic is even "worse" than the old one, as it still pins sizes to things that don't have a fixed size, and definite sizes to things that can have sizes varying by a factor of 1000, easily. So, I removed that as well. Pretty pictures that distract make your question worse, honestly. Stop adding these.)

Comment: @All - We're getting flags, so: Unless an edit is *required* by a site rule, then ultimately the Q or A author can rollback an edit, if they strongly disagree with it i.e. *within limits* (which are moderator judgement calls) authors "own" their content. So if *autodidact* wants an apparently relevant graphic in their Q, even if others disagree about its helpfulness, they can have it (but its source must be [referenced](/help/referencing)). A comment with *constructive* criticism is OK. For background on editing see [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/08/in-defense-of-editing/). Thanks.

Comment: Probably better to think of the processor die as a thin piece of silicon that generates a lot of heat. The cooling systems used for modern processors are pretty amazing for mass produced consumer goods. I think all the focus on atoms and nm and transistors is totally misguided here. The focus should be on the silicon die as a single source of heat.

Comment: @mkeith that "thin piece of silicon" why it need 360 Watt why not only 50 watt or less? Isn't supposed to be that way since we are making small semiconductors?

Comment: I think it is better to stick to one topic at a time. But processors have two main mechanisms of heating. One is static power loss (caused by leakage through transistor gates) and the other is dynamic power loss (caused by charging and discharging transistor gates). Cramming more and more smaller transistors into a single die has led to increase in static power losses. Running faster and faster has led to an increase in dynamic power loss. You may feel that 360 Watts is too much. But presumably, for that particular chip, the designers could not do any better.

Comment: @mkeith this make sence to me so its problem of performance, you can add your answer thank you  now i can sleep peacefully.

Comment: @autodidact - Hi, Since you have said that the comment from *mkeith* (now copied into a "community wiki" answer) does answer your question, please consider "[áccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" that answer, to show that the question is effectively closed.

Comment: @autodidact - P.S. It is also possible that *mkeith* will repost their comment as an answer, and then you can accept that one (or any other answer which you decide is the best answer to your question).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it is better to stick to one topic at a time. But processors have two main mechanisms of heating. One is static power loss (caused by leakage through transistor gates) and the other is dynamic power loss (caused by charging and discharging transistor gates). Cramming more and more smaller transistors into a single die has led to increase in static power losses. Running faster and faster has led to an increase in dynamic power loss. You may feel that 360 Watts is too much. But presumably, for that particular chip, the designers could not do any better.

This [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651721/how-much-power-can-a-6-nm-transistor-handle/651927#comment1732258_651721) by [mkeith](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/57037/mkeith) answers my question.

The central processing unit (CPU) is a unit meant to process and compute data, and that doesn't necessitate a lot of power - at least, it should not. Now days almost all people in the world have a smartphone which uses a microprocessor on it and those devices stand for many hours due to their efficiency.  Even laptops are equipped with CPUs that are more efficient than desktops servers CPUs.

[image]

[Graphe source](https://m.blog.naver.com/beahey/90185364333)

This graph shows the I/O power needed, and for that reason the comment on this answer answers my question hope now things are clear to you too.

Comment: autodidact - Hi, Following the advice [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303) for when a comment answers a question (which you have confirmed it does in [your comment above](/posts/comments1732270)), I have added suitable quote syntax and links. I have also set it to "community wiki" since it would be inappropriate for someone to gain points based on copying a comment from another site member (and "community wiki" answers don't pass points to any authors, although they can/should still be upvoted, if found to be useful).

Answer (score 7):

> my question is about power that is going to to that tiny transistor.

First, you're off by some orders of magnitude here. Just the conductive path through each fin of a 6nm transistor is still composed of millions of atoms, so it will absolutely dwarf things like individual molecules. Then each transistor is composed of multiple fins, with more being added as needed for higher power transistors, so these can be large structures.

Second, while power is dissipated when transistors switch, there are also resistive losses in the countless miles of metal wiring connecting all of these transistors together, so thermally it's not accurate to think of all the power being dissipated in the few million atoms that make up individual transistors. Losses are actually distributed over a wider area, which makes them more manageable.

Finally, if you do have a single transistor with high loss (perhaps one that constantly changes state while driving a large load), power dissipation is only limited by how efficiently you can cool it. Hot spots do absolutely limit chip performance, but designers know this and can space out hot transistors, give them more fins to spread out dissipation (although that also increases loss), and design efficient cooling solutions. Since silicon is extremely good at conducting heat, you can have a lot of localized dissipation while still keeping temperature reasonable.

Comment: Power dissipation is also limited by degradation effects such as electromigration destroying interconnect and hot carries destroying gate oxide. Chips can and will still fail even when cooled well if too much power is pushed through them.

Comment: @user1850479 Shouldn't be less? CPU operate with only ~1V  so 360 amps!! Even the AWG 40 can't handle that at his fusing current rating.

Comment: @autodidact I don't know where you take that number from, but remember, a CPU does *not* get warm because it's a large resistor that DC flows into. Losses in CPUs are different, and currents aren't DC.

Comment: @autodidact I see you edited your post with a comment about current, but it is not clear what your question is. Maybe you could clarify what it is you are still looking for or else accept this as an answer to your question if I've answered it.

Comment: @user1850479 i apreciate your time i really do But your answer did not satisfy me. My question is how much power can a transistor let say 6 nm^3 can handle?

Comment: @autodidact Transistors 6 nm^3 do not exist, so the answer would be zero watts, at least until such a thing is invented.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, the 360 W power consumption isn't normally sustained load, unless the server is under 100% load all the time, which is not wanted.

Secondly, it is important to understand that even with 100% sustained load, the CPU is consuming these 300 something amperes in very, very short bursts.

The clock ticks at, say, 5 GHz, that is a 200 ps interval between clock ticks. The CPU will draw the currentonly franction of that 200 ps. Think of it like a peak current that comes in short (ps) bursts. Combined with the knowledge that whether something is "fried" or not is not dependent only on the amperes, but on the duration of the amperes.

Finally, the current has a heating character, so if you can cool the CPU so the temperature stays below the T_junction, you can put as many watts as you want into the CPU.

Comment: Let say the CPU is PERFECT in your opinion how should it consume in place of 360 watt?

Comment: @autodidact Im not sure I completely understand what is you question about, could you specify what do you mean by "how should it consume in place of 360 watt"?

Comment: Siver have a look at my answer i already explained there what i meant :)